# How to create DAOs/model for a table structure like this

Tags: java, dao, data-access-layer

```
ACCOUNT [ account_id number, name varchar, ... ]
ACCOUNT_URL_XREF [ account_url_id number, url_id number, account_id number]
URL [url_id number, url_name varchar, ... ]
```

Above is a description of table structure. These reference tables tend to confuse me, because when you are creating a DAO, say, AccountDAO, which will return Account objects, should this object contain a List of Url objects by default? Or should I create AccountUrlDAO? So, given an account id, I would query AccountUrlDao and get the url_ids and then query the UrlDao to get all the Urls?

Answer (score 1):

This is a judgement call; it is a question of weighing convenience (and code maintainability) against performance.  If you expect that most of the time you access an account, you'll want to access the list of URLs, then by all means include the list.  But if you expect to be accessing loads of accounts while rarely accessing the URLs, then don't include the list by default; you'll just be wasting time and memory by retrieving them from the database.

Also, watch out for dependency loops.  For example, if you have the Account object include a list of URLs, and the URL object includes a list of Accounts, then you could end up with trouble, if you're not careful.